# Export notebook as epub?

Tags: export, notebooks, cdf-format

Is there a way (preferably easy!) to have Mathematica export a notebook or CDF as an epub document, to be read on an e-reader?  It would certainy seem possible to export as HTML, and then use epub-generating tools to turn the HTML document and supporting files into an epub; but I'm hoping that the work could be done by Mathematica.  (The "work" would include creating manifest and navigation files and a table of contents.)

Answer (score 3):

There are a million (or more) ways to convert an RTF to an ePub, so saving your notebook to RTF is probably the way to go.

Comment: I would add that if a command line converter is available it could be called from *Mathematica* using `Run`